# Javascript HTML how to draw an image on a canvas every frame

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to make a browser game, and Right now, I'm figuring out how to display an image via javascript. I've read a number of posts related to the subject, and about how image loading is Asynchronous, but despite the fact that I have an onload before setting the image source, it doesn't seem to be working the way I want it to.

I've also seen a number of posts related to displaying an image on a page permanently, but this image is only supposed to display when a certain variable is set a certain way, and that variable should be able to turn on or off.

Note that the following code was written via Microsoft's .net system in Visual Studio, so a fair bit of the HTML code isn't present on this page. However, I believe that everything relevant is shown here.

Please note that in the actual code, all this is separated across multiple files and pages; I have grouped it all here for your convenience. The navbar and directional buttons will not function, ignore them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body class="background_gradient">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark dark-bg border-bottom box_shadow mb-0">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Portfolio</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="MainDiv">
        <main role="main" class="pb-0" style="width:100%">
            
            <div class="container-fluid purple_gradient text-center">
    <h1>Snake Game</h1>
</div>
<div class="buffer"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fancy_text_box">
        <div class="container buffer">
            <div class="ghostly_text_box text-center">
                <h1>By the power of Javascript, here is a playable snake game:</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="buffer"></div>

            <div class="ghostly_text_box text-center">
                <canvas onload="draw()" class="simple_text_box" id="SnekGamCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="buffer"></div>

        <a class="button glo_button big_r_button big_text" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Back to Home</a>

        <div class="buffer"></div>
    </div>

    <!--The code be here but if you are reading this you probably already knew that-->
    <script>

        //canvas elements
        var canvas = document.getElementById("SnekGamCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var px = canvas.width / 2;
        var py = canvas.height / 2;

        var snekColor = "#EC942D";

        //images
        var seel = new Image();
        seel.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(seel, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        seel.src = "~/images/SEEL.jpg"

        var gameState = 3;

        function draw() {

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            if (gameState == 0) {
                //this hasn't been implemented yet
                startMenu();
            }
            else if (gameState == 1) {
                //this hasn't been implemented yet either
                playGame();
            }
            else if (gameState == 2) {
                //ditto
                gameOver();
            }
            else {
                //This is the part I'm trying to get to work right now.
                
                
                ctx.drawImage(seel, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                //I've managed to get this draw_Ball function to work, so I know I'm hitting this code.
                //draw_Ball(100, 100, 50, snekColor)
            }

        }
        setInterval(draw, 10);

        function startMenu() {

        }

        function playGame() {

        }

        function gameOver() {

        }

        //this function was stolen from stack overflow
        function showImage(width, height, image_source, alt_text) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = image_source;
            img.width = width;
            img.height = height;
            img.alt = alt_text;

        }

        function draw_Ball(bx, by, size, ballColor) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(bx, by, size, 0, (Math.PI * 2));
            ctx.fillStyle = ballColor;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

    </script>

</div>
            
            
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer dark-bg text-light">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - Portfolio - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="../jsc3d-master/jsc3d/jsc3d.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please group the HTML and JS in one snippet (that's the point of a snippet, so it can be run)

Comment: @Jeremy Thille How am I meant to add the image file into the mix? I can't put that in the snippet, can I?

Comment: You are loading your image at every frame, that's one new request every ten milliseconds. Load it only once, before you start your loop.

Comment: @Kaiido That's not an option, I'm afraid. I need it to be possible for the image to be there one frame and gone the next.

Comment: You don't need to **load** it every frame no. Once again, load it only once, before you start your loop. Ps: to load an image, you set its `src`.

Comment: Do you get any error messages on the console?  The image is being drawn on the canvas immediately after settting the `src` attrirbute, at which point it is unlikely to have loaded. An additional `load`  event*handler*  is being added to the image object every time `draw` is called in state 3, so when the load event occurs, every handler will want to draw the image on the canvas.  You probably want to change to a fresh state immediately after adding the image `src` attribute.

Comment: I've moved the image loading code to before the draw function, but it's still not drawing the image. I'm not seeing any obvious error messages in the output log... that said, I am apparently getting errors in the snippet here on Stack overflow, but I think that's because I haven't put the image file here for the snippet to use. Is that possible?

Comment: Don't start the timer until the image has loaded?

Comment: @traktor to do that, would I add the code for loading the image into the canvas's onload function?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cofwkerh/ Your updated code works.

Comment: @Kaiido I see. In that case, the issue must be that Javascript can't see the image in my file system. Loading it from "~/images/SEEL.jpg" works for HTML... is there a reason it wouldn't work for javascript?

Comment: Well..  ~/ would be your home directory... Do you have a server running? Does this server has access to this home directory?

Comment: It's not a server right now... I'm running it via Visual Studio. So far, accessing images from this filesystem hasn't given me issues, either on Visual Studio or after porting it to my web hosting platform.